# Как конвертировать строку в int или float в python если в ней есть строковые данные?

Tags: python, float, int

Есть строка: 188 990 тг

Как это число привести к инту вырезав мусор без replace?

обычная конвертация int(str) не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '188 990 тг'
x = int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isnumeric()))
```

Comment: Всёравно вывод неверен (188990+0j)

Comment: Вы что-то делаете не так https://ideone.com/Ndo8hx

Comment: Всё верно, на return в коде у функции стоял лишний параметр, всё работает.

Comment: @Иван если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: А нет не помогло, строки разные. На [u'68\xc2\xa0780\xa0'] не срабатывает само собой, тут должно быть 68780

Comment: И вы снова делаете что-то не так https://ideone.com/9S5Rkm

Comment: price = tree.xpath('//p[@class="b-product__price"]/text()') вот так я строку получаю. price = int(''.join(c for c in price if c.isnumeric())) выдает ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Потому что `xpath` возвращает не строку, а список.

Comment: Собственно да, в первом варианте было так price = tree.xpath('//span[@class="sum"]/text()')[1], поэтому получался один элемент. Тут в списке всего один элемент, добавление [0] к работе не приводит :(

Comment: решено, дальше стояла провера на len, а он с интами не работает.

Comment: @Иван повторю, [ответы принято отмечать решениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/204271).